# How to change the block size in tftpd to transfer large files efficiently

Tags: tftp

I have installed the TFTP client application by following the below link:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/201505/how-do-i-install-and-run-a-tftp-server

By default, the block size of the **TFTP packet header is 512 bytes**.
I am trying to increase the blocksize by adding the `--blocksize 1468` flag into `/etc/xinetd.d/tftp` file by following the below reference:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/644031/tftpd-hpa-how-can-i-set-blksize-option

After making the required changes by following the above link still I am getting the same 512 Data packet size. Can anyone share me the code for the same so I can change the block size configuration for the same?

Answer (score 0):

The `-B` option is what to use on CentOS:

```
server_args = -B 1468 -v -s /var/lib/tftpboot
```